# Conditional Sum in pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

Good day All

I would kindly please like your assistance.
So i would like to create a new column called df['Income_Status'], using the customers Income Proxy.

```
Where 
  1 = High Avg Income,        
  2 = Med Avg Income,         
  3= Low Avg Income
```

This is how my data set looks like:

```
  Customer_id     Income_Proxy  Average_Income_Proxy   Standard_dev_Income_Proxy

    123              7681559.15       44288.02                176568.76
    456              15156.29         44288.02                176568.76
    789              50497.69         44288.02                176568.76
    096              44138.41         44288.02                176568.76
    158              67866.45         44288.02                176568.76

The condition is:
IF INCOME_PROXY <= MEAN_INCOME_PROXY - (0.5)*&STD_INCOME_PROXY
then High Avg Income

IF INCOME_PROXY >= MEAN_INCOME_PROXY + (0.5)*STD_INCOME_PROXY
then Low Avg Income

else Low Avg Income
```

How do i go about creating a column that will give me the Income status, by using the condition provided.
And how will i write this condition in Pandas python format?

Comment: It seems in question is mistake, `then Low Avg Income

else Low Avg Income`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df.Income_Proxy <= df.Average_Income_Proxy - (0.5)* df.Standard_dev_Income_Proxy
m2 = df.Income_Proxy >= df.Average_Income_Proxy + (0.5)* df.Standard_dev_Income_Proxy

df['Income_Status'] = np.select([m1,m2], [1,3], default=2)
print (df)
   Customer_id  Income_Proxy  Average_Income_Proxy  Standard_dev_Income_Proxy  \
0          123    7681559.15              44288.02                  176568.76   
1          456      15156.29              44288.02                  176568.76   
2          789      50497.69              44288.02                  176568.76   
3           96      44138.41              44288.02                  176568.76   
4          158      67866.45              44288.02                  176568.76   

   Income_Status  
0              3  
1              2  
2              2  
3              2  
4              2
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, could you pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380425/how-to-split-and-categorize-value-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe