# how to split and categorize value in a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df,

```
    keys
0   one
1   two,one
2   " "
3   five,one
4   " "
5   two,four
6   four
7   four,five
```

and two lists,

```
 actual=["one","two"]
 syn=["four","five"]
```

I am creating a new row df["val"]
I am trrying to get the categories of the cells in `df["keys"]`. If anyone of the key is present in `actual` then i want to add actual in a new column but same row, If anyone of the value is not present in actual then i want the corresponding `df["val"] as syn`. and it should not do anything on the white space cells.

My desired output is,

output_df

```
    keys      val
0   one       actual
1   two,one   actual
2   " "        
3   five,one  actual
4   " "
5   two,four  actual
6   four      syn
7   four,five syn
```

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: if your actual sets have more elements than just 2, you may want to test this again.

Comment: I will test with 3 elements and update you @coldspeed

Comment: More like 5-10 would be a good benchmark ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , it is working fine with more than 5 elements, can you help me applying ignore case when mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with double conditions for check membership by compare `set`s:

```
s = df['keys'].str.split(',')
m1 = s.apply(set) & set(actual)
m2 = s.apply(set) & set(syn)

df['part'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['actual','syn'], default='')
print (df)
        keys    part
0        one  actual
1    two,one  actual
2                   
3   five,one  actual
4                   
5   two,four  actual
6       four     syn
7  four,five     syn
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [143]: %%timeit 
     ...: s = df['keys'].str.split(',')
     ...: m1 = s.apply(set) & set(actual)
     ...: m2 = s.apply(set) & set(syn)
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 160 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ' s solution
In [144]: %%timeit
     ...: v = df['keys'].str.split(',',expand=True)
     ...: m1 = v.isin(["one","two"]).any(1)
     ...: m2 = v.isin(["four","five"]).any(1)
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 193 ms per loop
```

**Caveat**:

Performance really depends on the data.

Comment: Caveat is a synonym for "disadvantage"... "The caveat of this approach is the memory consumption"... In your case, it's just a "note", not a caveat ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - I dont know if creating new dataFrames or creating lists is more consumed. But if I test it `s = df['keys'].str.split(',').apply(set).memory_usage()
v = df['keys'].str.split(',',expand=True).memory_usage()` and `print (s)
print(v.sum())` it seems `DataFrame` lost here. But not sure how the best test it.

Comment: what, headache, Will I be facing any issue when doing with larger data?

Comment: @pyd - dont worry, cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is wrong, because it was tested by `memory_usage()` and unfortnately his solution is more memory consumed. But you can test it too with real data by code in comment above.

Comment: okay @jezrael , can you help me applying ignore case while mapping m1, m2. Sometimes ill have values like ONe,TwO and it should match with my lower case actual list

Comment: @pyd - you can use `s = df['keys'].str.lower().str.split(',')` - first convert to lowercase and then apply my solution.

Comment: thank you, but is this the only option converting to lowercase? cant we use re.IGNORECASE here /

Comment: I am on phonr only, so untested solutuin. `pat = '|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(x) for x in actual])
m1 = df['keys'].str.findall(pat, flag=re.IGNORECASE).astype(bool)` and similar for another list. `pat = '|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(x) for x in syn])
m2 = df['keys'].str.findall(pat, flag=re.IGNORECASE).astype(bool)`

Comment: Another solution is`pat = '|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(x) for x in actual])
m1 = df['keys'].str.contains(pat, flag=re.IGNORECASE)` and similar for another list. `pat = '|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(x) for x in syn])
m2 = df['keys'].str.contains(pat, flag=re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: @jezrael I am getting type error `TypeError: contains() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flag'` for both the solutions

Comment: @pyd - I test it and need change `flag` to `flags` only.

Answer (score 1):

First, split on comma and expand words into their own cells.

```
v = df['keys'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

Next, form two masks, one for `actual` and another for `syn`, using `isin` + `any`. These will be used to label the rows.

```
m1 = v.isin(["one","two"]).any(1)
m2 = v.isin(["four","five"]).any(1)
```

Finally, use `np.select` or `np.where` to label the rows based on the masks computed.

```
df['val'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['actual', 'syn'], default='')
```

Or,

```
df['val'] = np.where(m1, 'actual', np.where(m2, 'syn', ''))
```

```
df

        keys     val
0        one  actual
1    two,one  actual
2                   
3   five,one  actual
4                   
5   two,four  actual
6       four     syn
7  four,five     syn
```

---

**Details**

`v`

```
      0     1
0   one  None
1   two   one
2        None
3  five   one
4        None
5   two  four
6  four  None
7  four  five
```

`m1`

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

`m2`

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
dtype: bool
```

```
np.select([m1, m2], ['actual', 'syn'], default='')
array(['actual', 'actual', '', 'actual', '', 'actual', 'syn', 'syn'],
      dtype='<U6')
```